# Using ML predictions for Online Scheduling Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, algorithmic-randomness

I've read [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/73a427badebe0e32caa2e1fc7530b7f3-Paper.pdf) on improving worst case performances of online scheduling algorithms. Was wondering if anyone had any insight on the follow-up question, if you could use the error distribution from the prediction to improve the bounds. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!